# Increased CPU usage and server response time

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, memory, central-processing-unit, memcached

Over the past 10 days, I'm suddenly experiencing increased CPU usage on my website with CPU usage reaching 100% three times. During that time I'm unable to SSH to my website so I haven't been able to figure out what is actually using that much CPU. My website is a Django application using Apache2, PostgreSQL and Memcached hosted on DigitalOcean (1GB Ram, 30GB SSD Disk, Ubuntu 14.04 x64).

Here is the output of top currently.

```
top - 11:00:37 up  8:40,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.21, 0.22
Tasks:  81 total,   2 running,  79 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 24.3 us,  2.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 69.1 id,  4.0 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1017948 total,   918656 used,    99292 free,   124816 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   205868 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1084 www-data  20   0  833820 218516   5808 S 22.2 21.5   4:22.42 apache2
 3504 postgres  20   0  249560  22844  20036 S  3.0  2.2   0:00.09 postgres
  928 memcache  20   0  359596  35764    876 S  0.3  3.5   0:03.90 memcached
 1085 www-data  20   0  842852  14372   3044 S  0.3  1.4   0:19.76 apache2
 3477 root      20   0   24820   1532   1132 R  0.3  0.2   0:00.27 top
    1 root      20   0   33384   2688   1400 S  0.0  0.3   0:10.75 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.91 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  0.0  0.0   0:01.96 rcuos/0
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.51 watchdog/0
   13 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
```

Here is the Apache conf file

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is my VirtualHost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com [nocase]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com$1 [last,redirect=301]

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess example python-path=/home/abc/example:/home/abc/example/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/abc/example/wsgi.py

    DocumentRoot /home/abc/example

    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /home/abc/example/static/

    <Directory /home/abc/example/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /home/abc/example/media/

    <Directory /home/abc/example/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|svg|woff|eot|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js|json)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/javascript          js
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                   otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz 
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz
</Ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</Ifmodule>
```

Here is the graph of CPU, Disk and Bandwidth usage over the past month

[image: Monthly CPU Usage]
[image: Monthly Disk Usage]
[image: Monthly Bandwidth Usage]

As you can see the CPU usage spiked 3 times over the past couple of days. I had to reboot my droplet to bring it down. The CPU usage generally used to vary between 0-5% up until a few days ago but has increased now.

The response time for the website has also increased to about 4 seconds. The response time is high even when the CPU load is not high. Everything seemed to be working fine up until around 10 days and I haven't made any changes to my configuration since then. There hasn't been an increase in the traffic with daily traffic being around 1500 visitors. How can I identify what's causing this issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don`t have an autoritative answer but take a look on your entropy levels. Take a look on this post to understand why: http://www.lincvz.info/2013/09/22/linux-low-entropy-pool-for-devrandom-after-system-upgrade/

Add please the output of :
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

Comment: @vfbsilva The output ranges from 145-180.

Comment: Okay you DO have a problem on your machine regarding entropy. Thing is ssh relies on the random numbers avaliable on their kernel to give you an unique key to your session. If you deplete all the entropy from the kernel it has to block to generate more numbers. This explains your cpu peaks and impossibility to log in via ssh. Install the haveged package http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/ and give me the entropy numbers again please. Also check the cpu graph

Comment: Running a process (`cat`) consumes entropy. A value between 100 and 200 is very common on servers with medium activity. It would be an issue if it goes lower. Moreover, a measure in a normal mode of operation is not relevant, because IO activities generate entropy thus the measure should be taken during peaks. As visitor count grows, this is normal to see higher CPU, network and disk stressed a little bit more. Notice how CPU usage liftoff while disk and network activity are collapsing. Likely the application (Django) is the culprit.

Comment: @Xavier Lucas well pointed about IO generating entropy I forgot to mention that to the OP. OP take a look here https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjACOAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommunities.ca.com%2Fthread%2F101859572&ei=AvdnVKfmF_WTsQSbg4GABg&usg=AFQjCNGZCrPqrS48KVh2mrQh_3C7P1_5dg&sig2=_fS3JcyPCk18jALh--i5qw
But I still find 100~200 too low still I could not find documentation for the minimum recomended value

Comment: I'm puzzled that no-one has commented on the sharp increase in inbound network traffic around the start of the problem. I guess this could be a symptom (clients resending requests) but I'd want to convince myself of that. Have you tried looking for unusual network connections with tcpdump or similar?